# Form states with "and" and "or" conditions

Tags: 7, javascript

Using form API in D7, I need to use from states to setup a visible input with this condition :

```
field1 = value A AND (field2 = value B OR value C OR value D)
```

Something like this, but this example doesn't run :

```
'#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        array(':input[name="question_inhabitant_type"]' => array('value' => 'owner')),
        'AND',
        array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house100')),
        'OR',
        array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house150')),
        'OR',
        array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house200')),
      ),
    ),
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `or/xor` in form states. For `and`, continuation of the conditions is enough. For example your code the condition can be written as:

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    array(':input[name="question_inhabitant_type"]' => array('value' => 'owner')),
    array(
      array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house100')),
      'or',
      array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house150')),
      'or',
      array(':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array('value' => 'house200')),
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Note:** jQuery 1.7 doesn't support OR/XOR's for `#states`. So, make sure you have latest jQuery version on you site (>1.7).

Unfortunately the above code didn't worked as expected. Please help through your comments to correct it. Also meanwhile you can try this code:

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="question_inhabitant_type"]' => array('value' => 'owner'),
    ':input[name="question_building_type"]' => array(
      array('value' => 'house100'),
      array('value' => 'house150'),
      array('value' => 'house200'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Jquery default version is set on 1.10. According to your example if I set only "or" condition it's working. If I copy paste the code, it's doesn't run :'(

Comment: can you please try the code provided on bottom?

Comment: the second example is running :D ty