# Drupal 8 Webform : Regular expression in conditions to check specific day of the week

Tags: webforms

I am setting another webform on Drupal 8. 
I want to enable some fields based on the day of the week selected. 
I used JS on a site with Drupal 7, it is working fine,  thanks to JSDrupal.

I would like to implement it on the Drupal 8 site with a regexp. 
I am using the HTML5 date field, not the Jquery datepicker.
My concern is the same than before :

if the Day selected on field DATE_D( a Date field) is Tuesday OR Thursday then hide SELECT( select field).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webform module for Drupal 8 supports patterns in the #states API (aka Conditional logic).

[image: Example of pattern in conditional logic]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry for the delay, had a busy day with students. But i am not using a select, i am using the HTML5 datepicker ( not jquery). It is not working with it or do i need to do additional things ?

Comment: You would have to write custom JS and PHP and calculate the day of the week and then conditionally hide/show the element

Comment: Thank you. So bottom line is, I have to use a select or write custom js and PHP. Thank for your help

Comment: I doesn't seems to work with radios option/value thought.. Only with select ?
Can't see that in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can achieve this without some JS involved.

You can use JS [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

You could try Form API [`#states`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x) and try to hide the desired select field if some other field's value matches your conditions.

```
$form['my_select_element'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#states' => [
    // Hide this field when the 'weekday' radio has 'tuesday' or 'thursday' selected.
    'invisible' => [
      ':input[name="field_weekday[und]"]' => ['value' => 'tuesday'],
      'or',
      ':input[name="field_weekday[und]"]' => ['value' => 'thursday'],
    ],
  ],
];
```

(`#states` with multiple conditions, [Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/192499/15055).)